# Pass Field Type as Class<T>

Tags: java, reflection, fieldtype

I have the following codes.

```
public <T> List<Object> types(Class<T> clazz) {
        Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
        List<Object> types = Arrays.stream(fields)
                .map(Field::getType)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return types;
}
```

I am struggling as how I would pass the field type as Class object later on.  I'll be using them in the reflection (`clazz` here is class `Contact`):

```
for (Object type : name(clazz)) {
            Method method = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("myMethod", type.getClass());
}
```

Assuming that `type` is a `String`, if I print it out as:
`System.out.println(type);`
output is: `class java.lang.String` but if I print it as:
`System.out.println(type.getClass();`
output is: `class java.lang.Class`. So if I pass it as `type.getClass()`, reflection complains:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Contact.myMethod(java.lang.Class)
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: the snippets have nothing in common, it's very unclear

Answer (score 2):

`Field::getType` returns a class. Why storing it into an `Object` in your collected stream  ?
Just collect them into a List of class.
Besides the parameterized type method scoped is helpless here. You don't want to infer any type.

That would give :

```
public List<Class<?>> types(Class<?> clazz) {
    Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
    List<Class<?>> types = Arrays.stream(fields)
                               .map(Field::getType)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return types;
}
```

Note that you collect declared fields and then you seem to want to use them in the method retrieved by reflection. What is not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for trying to help me. I, however, bumped into the luck. I just changed:

```
type.getClass()
```

to

```
type.toString().getClass()
```

Comment: ``type.toString().getClass()`` will return ``java.lang.String`` everytime for any (non-null) object. The result of a toString is always... a String :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
public <T> List<Object>
```

By

```
public <T> List<T>
```